# React: dynamically add input fields in dynamic input fileds

Tags: json, reactjs

I want to make a form . which consist of a shop creation where 3 input fileds are plan name, descriptions, cuisuine . after that three input fileds which i want to add dynamically for duration of plan, maximum duration and price. i can add n numbers of duration and after that i also want to dynamically add all the input fields on a button clicked
**plan name**,
**description**
**cuisuine**
*duration*

Comment: hi @Tarun Choudhary and welcome to Stackoverflow. Currently, it is not entirely clear what your question is. Try to make it as specific as possible. You should also provide some code of what you already implemented, what you tried and which error or problem you are currently running into. Else it will be really hard for people to help you. Also, Stackoverflow's purpose is not to do the coding for you - so you should at least have tried something before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand the question, but in the following way you can generate a set of input fields dynamically. I hope it helps :)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Example() {
  const model = { name: "", desc: "", cuisuine: "" };
  const [durations, setDurations] = useState([model]);
  const fields = ["name", "desc", "cuisuine"];

  function handleChange(field, index, value) {
    let newDurations = durations;
    newDurations[index][field] = value;
    setDurations(newDurations);
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
      {durations.map((v, i) => (
        <div
          style={{ border: "1px solid #ccc", padding: "20px" }}
          key={`duration-${i}`}>
          {fields.map(field => (
            <input
              key={`duration-${i}-${field}`}
              type="text"
              name={field}
              placeholder={field}
              onChange={({ target }) => handleChange(field, i, target.value)}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
      <button onClick={() => setDurations([...durations, model])}>
        Add field
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```